# Unable to send email with JavaMail android APi

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, email-client

I have been trying to send an email from android using JavaMail Api for Android. I enabled `lesssecure` option too. 
So far I have done following..
package com.emazdoor.encymail;

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "587";//"465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {
//          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
                }
            });

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    // more of the getters and setters …..
    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        this._to = toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        this._from = string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        this._subject = string;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final com.emazdoor.encymail.Mail m = new com.emazdoor.encymail.Mail(
                "emailhere@gmail.com", "password");
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    String[] toArr = {"grg@gmail.com",
                            "emailhere@gmail.com"};
                    m.setTo(toArr);
                    m.setFrom("emailhere@gmail.com");
                    m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.");
                    m.setBody("Email body.");
                    m.send();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Email was sent successfully.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SendEmail", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }

    }
```

But I kept getting this error

```
05-17 23:41:21.536  21305-21714/com.emazdoor.encymail E/SendEmail﹕ null
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
            at com.emazdoor.encymail.Mail.send(Mail.java:112)
            at com.emazdoor.encymail.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
            at com.emazdoor.encymail.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:29)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your credentials were rejected.

Comment: Nope, i got an email stating that someone is trying to access my account in the account I used to send an email.

Comment: Okay, I was disabling `lesssecureapp` flag at GMAIL. Now fixed but email is only sent once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turning `Lesssecureappaccess` on did the trick. Although only once email is sent.